# In Unity shaders, how is IN.worldRefl calculated?

Tags: unity, shaders, geometry, reflection-rendering

I want to know how the world reflection vector in shaders is calculated so that I can manipulate it, but there is no documentation on what it does or how Unity calculates it. How is the reflection vector calculated and exactly what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

The reflection vector is calculated as below:

```
float3 refl = 2.0 * o.Normal * dot(o.Normal, IN.viewDir) - IN.viewDir;
//float3 refl = IN.worldRefl;
```

That equation is similar to specular reflection.